# How to select the correct TransactionManager when using R2DBC together with Flyway and JDBC

Tags: micronaut, r2dbc, micronaut-data, r2dbc-postgresql, micronaut-test

**Setup:**

- micronaut 3.7.2
- micronaut-data 3.8.1, micronaut-data-r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql 0.9.2
- Flyway 8.5.13, micronaut-jdbc-hikari, micronaut-flyway 5.4.1, postgresql 42.5.0
- testcontainers (jdbc, r2dbc, postgresql) 1.17.5
- io.micronaut.test-resources 3.6.2

**Test Configuration (conf4k):**

```
datasources {
    default {
        dialect=POSTGRES
        options {
            currentSchema=default
        }
    }
}
r2dbc {
    datasources {
        default {
            dialect=POSTGRES
            options {
                currentSchema=default
            }
        }
    }
}
flyway {
    datasources {
        default {
            enabled=true
            locations="classpath:databasemigrations"
            schemas=["default"]
            create-schemas=true
        }
    }
}
test-resources {
  containers {
    postgres {
      image-name="postgres:12.12"
      hostnames=["localhost"]
    }
  }
}
```

**Preconditions:**

To make Flyway and micronaut data use the same database and testcontainer, the datasource of both needs to be named alike.

**Problem:**

Because of JDBC and R2DBC beeing used at the same time, synchronous and reactive TransactionManagers beans are created and I get the following error, when I use @Transactional:

```
Multiple possible bean candidates found: [io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManager, io.micronaut.transaction.sync.SynchronousFromReactiveTransactionManager]
```

**Thoughts:**

I thought, I could solve that with @TransactionalAdvice, but since both datasources need to have the same name, this is not possible. I tried to name the datasources differently, but does not work at all.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with using blocking JDBC calls in Reactor reactive calls. Using R2DBC and all code reactive, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Hantsy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893898/hantsy) mentioned in his post, adding transactions programmatically using `R2dbcOperations#withTransaction()` is a temporary workaround until Flyway finally supports R2DBC. Please upvote [here](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2502).

Since I use Kotlin and Coroutines, the code is suboptimal but ok for a hopefully ephemeral solution. To use that in Kotlin, one has to wrap the body of the function passed to `withTransaction` in mono `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change the datasource name of Jdbc(default) and Flyway(Flyway depends on Jdbc Datasouce) to another name, then in your Jdbc Repository, use a `@TransactionalAdvice` to select it.

I have a Micronaut example using Flyway and R2dbc in the same project.

But I have not tried `@Transactional`, for the transaction handling, I was using `R2dbcOperations.withTransaction`, it works well.

```java
public Mono<Long> deleteAll() {
        var sql = "DELETE  FROM customers";
        return Mono.from(
                r2dbcOperations.withTransaction(status ->
                        Mono.just(status.getConnection())
                                .flatMap(connection -> Mono
                                        .from(connection.createStatement(sql).execute())
                                        .flatMap(result -> Mono.from(result.getRowsUpdated()))
                                )
                )
        );
}
```

Check [my Micronaut R2dbc example here](https://github.com/hantsy/micronaut-sandbox/tree/master/data-r2dbc), hope it is helpful.

Comment: Since I use test-resources and this plugin forces me to use the same name for both datasources, this won't work. I now have two options: Using two different names, removing test-resources amd configure the testcontainers myself (as I did earlier). Or I strip flyway completly out of the project and run it as a sidecar in my k8s setup.

Comment: @macmillancodes According to test-resource doc, it just add test dependencies and simplify test framework config, I do not think it will affect your dataources in the application.